# How can I call my functions like this "$(obj).my_function()"?

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering how can I call my own function like this:

```
$("#calendar").my_calendar();
```

"Where my_calendar" is my function name.

Thanks.

Comment: show us the function definition of  `my_calendar`

Comment: add function to jQuery prototype. Is it your question???  https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Yes, @A.Wolff I didn't know how they call this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jQuery.fn.extend()` method extends the jQuery prototype (`$.fn`) object to provide new methods that can be chained to the `jQuery()` function.

```
$.fn.extend({
  my_calendar: function(){...}
});
```

Comment: Perfect @ryan-dantzler!